# What are smart clothes?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I can't seem to start this mission for Lester using Michael, with the requirement being that I should come in "smart clothes". I tried changing clothes in my house (polo and jeans, or a full suit outfit) but I can't seem to start it. What is the right one to wear? And should it even be bought as well?

Comment: You need to get a suit. There is a shop that has really nice clothes. You can pick up a suit there. However, I believe Michael already own one or two. If you go to his house just go to suits and put one on

Comment: I bought one for ~$5,000! Didn't realise he already had some :D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [this forum thread](http://gtaforums.com/topic/594657-lester-mission-smart-clothes/), [one post](http://gtaforums.com/topic/594657-lester-mission-smart-clothes/#entry1063377925) says:

> Alright, go to Michael's house and go to his wardrobe, pick "full suit" and there should be two of them(grey and blue). Pick either one and then you'll be ready.

[Another post in the same thread](http://gtaforums.com/topic/594657-lester-mission-smart-clothes/#entry1063376941) notes this caveat:

> Finally got it to work. I used the same suit as before (the first in Mike's wardrobe) but this time I made sure not to have any blood on my suit from car crashes, shoot-outs, etc. Looks like that was the problem.

This information leads me to believe that **any full suit is the correct choice, but you must make sure to keep your suit clean until you talk to Lester.**

Comment: So that's what it is, the suit should be clean lol

Comment: So if the suit somehow gets dirty, how do you clean it?

Comment: @Nolonar To my knowledge, going to a wardrobe and putting the same or another suit on should do the trick. Beyond that, I'm not sure.